# CsvParser not working for missing double quotes

Tags: scala, csv, univocity

I have a messages in file like below and I am using `com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser` to split the string based on delimiter(in this case its `-`)

> 1-bc-"name"-def-address
>
> 1-abc-"name-def-address

I create my `CsvParser` object like

```
private val settings = new CsvParserSettings()
settings.getFormat.setDelimiter('-')
settings.setIgnoreLeadingWhitespaces(true)
settings.setIgnoreTrailingWhitespaces(true)
settings.setReadInputOnSeparateThread(false)
settings.setNullValue("")
settings.setMaxCharsPerColumn(-1)
val parser = new CsvParser(settings)
```

and parse the input message like :

```
    for (line <- Source.fromFile("path\\test.txt").getLines) {
  println(parser.parseLine(line).toList)
}
```

and the output is:

```
List(1, bc, name, def, address)
List(1, abc, name-def-address)
```

If you see the output you can see that for 1st message the string was split properly however for second message it takes everything as a value after first double quote. Does anyone know why the behavior is like this and how can I get the desired output? I am reading every message as a string to it should simple treat a quote/double quote as a character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of this library here. When the quote is found after your `-` delimiter, the parser will try to find a closing quote.

The easiest way around this is to make the parser simply ignore quotes with:

```
settings.getFormat().setQuote('\0');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for creating a wonderful utility :) Can you please explain what that `\0` stands for ?

Comment: Glad to help. `\0` is the null character.

Comment: I see one more issue here, I have a record like:
`10      0` i.e. values are separated with group separator, `1^]0^]^@^@^@^@^@^@^]0^]`  however I have char "^@" i.e. ascii "000" and when I add the setting `settings.getFormat().setQuote('\0');`and tries to split the string it ignores the delimiter after "^@" and if I removes the setting it properly splits the string. Can you please help me here?

Comment: Use a non-character then: '\uFFFF' instead of '\0'

Comment: so I need to have `settings.getFormat().setQuote('\uFFFF');` ? I need to ignore quote and non-character both and I tried adding both the settings but still facing same issue.

Comment: never mind, Thanks for your help `'\uFFFF'` this solves both.